# In PlayN Graphics interface, what's the difference between height and screenHeight methods?

Tags: playn

I mean in the case of the main platform interface (i.e. `graphics().height()`). Looking at the [Graphics Interface docs](http://docs.playn.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/playn/core/Graphics.html), the **height** method states:

> Gets the height of the drawable surface, in pixels.

**screenHeight** states:

> Gets the height of the available screen real-estate, in pixels.

If there is a meaningful difference, in what cases might I prefer one to the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another useful way to understand the difference is that on the Java backend, `screenHeight` returns the full height of the screen (i.e. 1024 on a 1600x1024 display), whereas `height` returns the height of the window that is running the PlayN app.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do.

For example,we use `Graphics.screenHeight` to adjust  the game size in Android backend where there are a lot of different screen size devices, while `Graphics.height` adjust every layer we use to the default game size that it is used across the game in every platform.